# Lagrange interpolation perturbation in matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation, stability

This is my code for finding the centered coefficients for lagrange polynomial interpolation:

```
% INPUT
% f f scalar - valued function
% interval interpolation interval [a, b]
% n interpolation order
%
% OUTPUT
% coeff centered coefficients of Lagrange interpolant
function coeff = lagrangeInterp (f, interval , n)

a = interval(1);
b = interval(2);

x = linspace(a,b,n+1);
y = f(x);

coeff(1,:) = polyfit(x,y,n);
end
```

Which is called in the following script

```
%Plot lagrangeInterp and sin(x) together
hold on
x = 0:0.1*pi:2*pi;
for n = 1:1:4
    coeff = lagrangeInterp(@(x)sin(x),[0,2*pi],n);
    plot(x,polyval(coeff,x,'-'));
end
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y);
legend('1st order','2nd order','3rd order','4th order','sin(x)');
```

To check for stability I would like to perturb the function (eg g(x) = f(x) + epsilon). How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a little trick for you.

You know `randn([m,n])` in matlab generate a m*n random matrix. The point is to generate a random vector, and interp1 to a function of x. Like this:

```matlab
x = linspace(a,b,n+1); % Your range of input
g = @(ep,xx)f(xx)+interp1(x,ep*randn([length(x),1]),xx);
```